# Assigning a Date Object to update

Tags: javascript, datetime, javascript-objects

I would like to know how to assign a date object in this scenario, I need to update lastUpdate, whenever user changes his details.

I also tried  `Object.assign(user.lastUpdated, new Date());`

```
exports.edit = (req, res, next) => {
    const userid = req.params.id;
    const errorHandler = (error) => {
        next(error);
    };
    const updateUser = (user) => {
        Object.assign(user, req.body);
    Object.assign(user.lastUpdated, new Date());// not working
        user.lastUpdated= new Date(); //not able to save this in database
        user.save().then(() => {
            res.json({
                uid: user.id,
                username: user.username,
                displayName: user.displayName,
                password:user.password,
                lastUpdated: user.lastUpdated// result should be last updated Date.

            });
        }).catch(errorHandler);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object. ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign ).

But in your code `Object.assign(user.lastUpdated, new Date());` what you are trying to do is join two values together. So it won't work.

Try like this : `Object.assign( user, { lastUpdated : new Date() } );`

Comment: It would "work" if *user.lastUpdated* is an object (we don't know whether it is or not). It copies the enumerable property names and values, but since a Date instance has no enumerable own properties, it does nothing. ;-) I think it would be better to use `user.lastUpdated = new Date().toISOString()` or whatever format the database expects.